# Many to Many query Find all "recipes" with XX ingredients

Tags: java, sql, playframework, many-to-many

I'm doing a school project so I'm really not an advanced programmer and need a little help with a query that I need to make.

My db structure looks like this.

**RECIPE table:**

```
ID             BIGINT     19                                                  
DESCRIPTION    CLOB       2147483647                                               
NAME           VARCHAR    255
```

**INGREDIENT table:**

```
ID             BIGINT     19                                             
NAME           VARCHAR    255
```

**RECIPE_INGREDIENT table:**

```
RECIPE_ID         BIGINT    19                                            
INGREDIENTS_ID    BIGINT    19
```

**This is my model class Recipe**

```java
 @Entity
 public class Recipe extends Model {
    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Ingredient> ingredients;
    @Required
    @Unique
    public String name;
    @Lob
    @Required
    public String description;
```

**This is my model class Ingredient**

```
@Entity
public class Ingredient extends Model {
    @Required
    @Unique
    public String name;
```

The query I want to make is... I have a string with comma separated ingredients like `milk,flour,egg` for example. With that string I'd like to fetch all recipes which has exact those ingredients, lets say one Recipe only has `flour` as ingredient then that's true. Also a recipe with all mentioned etc etc.

I've modified a query string I found yesterday(can't remember where) but I can't get it to work.

**I get this error:**

```
IllegalArgumentException occured : org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: on near line 1, column 68 [select Recipe.name from models.Recipe inner join Recipe_Ingredient on Recipe.ID = Recipe_Ingredient.Recipe_ID inner join Ingredient on Recipe_Ingredient.Ingredient_ID = Ingredient.ID where Ingredient.name in ( 'milk') group by Recipe.name having count(*) = 2]
```

Any help would be much appreciated! And sorry if I made any mistakes with this post. It is my first here :)

**Edit:**

Query right now looks like this:

```
Query query = JPA.em().createQuery("SELECT Recipe.name "
    + "FROM Recipe INNER JOIN "
    + "Recipe_Ingredient ON Recipe.ID = Recipe_Ingredient.Recipe_ID "
    + "INNER JOIN Ingredient "
    + "ON Recipe_Ingredient.Ingredient_ID = Ingredient.ID "
    + "WHERE Ingredient.name "
    + "IN ("+ingredientsCSV+") "
    + "GROUP BY Recipe.name HAVING count(*) = 2");
```

Comment: You query is still incorrect, for you only add a quote in the beginning and end, thus looking for the ingredient 'milk, flour, egg', which probably doesn't exists. However, line 1 column 61 points to the join of RECIPE_INGREDIENT, which is strange. What dbms are you using?

Comment: Thank you, not sure what I was thinking, I'm debugging with only one ingredient so I didn't see the error I made.

I'm using the H2 relational db

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what is causing the error. The query looks syntactically fine to me and I see nothing that violates H2 select syntax.

Comment: Ok, that's good to know. Thank you, I'll carry on with trial and error style

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that with a simple query.

Why:
- You need to have way yo know if all ingredients are within your ingredient string.
Using `having` will not solve the problem is different recipes will have different amount of ingredients.

I'm not very familiar with how JPA works, but in pure sql for example mysql you could use a `view` to organize the data before you process it with a new query.

I'm Sorry that I can't help you with that query in JPA.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need quotes on:

... Ingredient.name in ('milk', 'flour', 'egg') group by....

Comment: Thanks, that is true! Still throws me same error though so I guess I've made more mistakes in that query

Comment: What's the message now?

Comment: Looks like you need to drop the "models." right after the FROM.


SELECT Recipe.name FROM Recipe
INNER JOIN Recipe_Ingredient ON Recipe.ID = Recipe_Ingredient.Recipe_ID
INNER JOIN Ingredient ON Recipe_Ingredient.Ingredient_ID = Ingredient.ID 
WHERE Ingredient.name IN ( 'milk') GROUP BY Recipe.name HAVING count(*) = 2

Comment: Note the SQL on the error message, it has models.Recipe.

Comment: I can't understand why it gets "added" for Recipe. And why not Ingredient then? Updated Query now @ question

Comment: Are you still getting the same error? If so, something on CreateQuery() must be adding the models.

Comment: Actually, perhaps your hibernate naming strategy is doing that.

Comment: Yeah I think you're right. I'll just fetch all and sort it with java code I guess. Deadline with project on monday so can't waste more time on this, thanks a bunch though!